# WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError flag is missing in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm migrating my code from a .NET 4.0 class library to a PCL library (targets .NET 4.0 and Windows 8).

One of the problems that I'm facing is that Microsoft did not include the `WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError` flag for the `WebException` API.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus(v=vs.110).aspx

As a result, I can no longer write code like this:

```
try
{
    // Get a response
    return webRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // Rethrow in case of transport errors (e.g. timeout)
    if (ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        throw;
    }

    // Else, return the response anyway
    return ex.Response;
}
```

What's really confusing is that the framework still uses this flag internally. You just can't use it in client code.

The only workaround that I can think of right now is casting `ex.Status` to `int` and comparing it to the value of `ProtocolError` (7). But that code would break in case they ever change the underlying value.

What's the new way of doing this?

**edit**: workarounds that I know of...

Compare by numeric value and throw if it is not 7

```
const int ProtocolError = 7;
if ((int)ex.Status != ProtocolError)
{
    throw;
}
```

Check if there is a response and throw if it is null

```
if (ex.Response == null)
{
    throw;
}
```

Feels like I'm still missing something?

Comment: The documentation you linked says it is supported in PCL. Let me have a look.

Comment: You have to look at the individual flags. Only some of them have the PCL logo, indicating that they're supported.

Comment: By the way, my code doesn't compile because they also removed the synchronous version of `GetResponse()`. But that's not an issue.

Comment: Indeed. Looking around it seems that the PCL version of `WebExceptionStatus` is an intersection of values supported by all PCL platforms. Couldn't find an official explanation though.

Comment: It's been almost an hour and I only got 3 views... what is going on?

Comment: I "fixed" it for now by checking if `ex.Response == null`